# Decouple angular from html completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Is it possible to decouple completely angular code from html so that I dont have any ng attributes in html.

I want to have simple plain html page that only have ids on form elements
and reference to my scripts where my angular based javascript resides.

So instead to write something like:

```
<input  id="somefieldid"  
ng-model="myctrl.value1" />
```

I want to have :

```
<input  id="somefieldid"   />
```

in html

and in script to do something like:

```
getById('somefieldid').setNgAttribute('ng-model','myctrl.value1');
```

I need some implementation of this `getById` and `setNgAttribute` that will work well with angular, if possible.

I need only few ng-attributes like `ng-model`, `ng-show` and `ng-click`, so I hope that's doable.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As indicated by the punchline of AngularJS on [their homepage](https://angularjs.org/), the framework is all about enhancing HTML - "HTML enhanced for web apps!". Why do you want to use Angular in this way?

Comment: That's an interesting question, but may I ask why you want to do this?  To me, it seems that you would be better off using something like jQuery since a lot of Angular's power and functionality come from its built-in directives (aka HTML attributes).

Comment: It's completely ok for others to find out you have made your app with angular. It won't pose any security threat to you any more than if you could hide all visible traces of it

Comment: I want to decouple angular from html so I can better divide work with my coworker on this project.

Comment: So that he can create plain html page with elements and I will create javascript fajl and attach angular code by id to elements. As long as he doesn't change element ids it can function this way for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly *can* do this but *shouldn't* need to.

I wrote a basic example of what you could do, [see the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fq5stynz/):

```
angular.module('app', []).run(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.myModel = {someValue: 'abc123'};

    var bodyElement = $("div#myContent");
    var compileTime = $compile(bodyElement)($rootScope);

    bodyElement.replaceWith(compileTime);
});

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

You can certainly expand on this idea if you want to use controllers and directives. You'll need to call `bodyElement.replaceWith(compileTime);` after you set ngAttributes with jQuery so that angular can reprocess the DOM.

Comment: But in your example angular specific attribute are in the html?! 
  can you put ng-model="myModel.someValue" somewhere in javascript in your fiddle instead of in html?

Comment: Ok. I managed to create a fiddle based on yours that solves my problem. https://jsfiddle.net/w1yr0n43/    Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model`, `ng-show` and `ng-click` can all be replicated with vanilla js or jquery.

ng-model:
`document.getElementById("myTextarea").value`

ng-click: `document.getElementById('anchorID').onclick=function(){/* some code */}`

ng-show: `document.getElementById('myElement').style.display = "block";`

Angular just provides convenience, but it sounds like you dont need a huge framework.

Comment: Well I know I can do it directly with vanilla js but that's not an option. This is something already build with angularjs. Just need to decouple it somehow from html now.